# Keycloak NGINX Reverse Proxy issue

Tags: nginx, keycloak, nginx-reverse-proxy

I get this following error upon my configuration for reverse proxy on Keycloak.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://keycloak.com/auth/admin/master/console/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://keycloak.com/auth/js/keycloak.js?version=vr8o5'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

How to fix this and what configuration needs to be added in nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default NGINX server config with mandatory headers:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        **add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;**

    }
```